# Download blobs from azure storage asynchronously and save them in DataTable

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, datatable

The following code shows how I download blobs from azure blob storage and save them into a DataTable:

```
foreach (var currIndexGroup in blobsGroupedByIndex)
{
    DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
    foreach (var currIndex in currIndexGroup)
    {       
        long fileByteLength = currIndex.Properties.Length;
        byte[] serializedAndCompressedResult = new byte[fileByteLength];
        currIndex.DownloadToByteArray(serializedAndCompressedResult, 0);
        dr[currIndex.Metadata["columnName"]] = DeflateStream.UncompressString(serializedAndCompressedResult);
    }
    dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

The problem is, that the download is pretty slow. 1000 real small blobs takes about 20 seconds to download. If I try to run it asynchronously by using `currIndex.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(serializedAndCompressedResult, 0);` the follow up line throws an exception `Bad state (invalid stored block lengths)`.

What is the right way to fill this datatable asynchronously?

Comment: Can you add your code with `DownloadToByteArrayAsync` ?

Comment: It is the same code but with DownloadToByteArrayAsync instead of DownloadToByteArray. I guess it's not working because the follow up line does not have serializedAndCompressedResult filled at the moment of execution. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You know that `DataTable` is not thread safe? Why not rather use a `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//the plan here is to make a model that holds your currIndex and byte array so you can return that model from a task
public class MyModel 
{
    public CloudBlockBlob CurrIndex {get;set;} 
    public byte[] FileBytes {get;set;}
}



foreach (var currIndexGroup in blobsGroupedByIndex)
{

    var myTasks = new List<Task<MyModel>>();
    foreach (var currIndex in currIndexGroup)
    {     
        myTasks.Add(Task<MyModel>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            var myModel = new MyModel();
            myModel.CurrIndex = currIndex;

            long fileByteLength = myModel.CurrIndex.Properties.Length;
            myModel.FileBytes = new byte[fileByteLength];
            currIndex.DownloadToByteArray(myModel.FileBytes, 0);
            return myModel;
        });
    }
    Task.WaitAll(myTasks.ToArray());

    foreach (var task in myTasks)
    {
        MyModel myModel = task.Result;
        DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
        dr[myModel.CurrIndex.Metadata["columnName"]] = DeflateStream.UncompressString(myModel.FileBytes);
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

You can further your parallelism by using a `Parallel.ForEach` on your outter foreach loop.  You would have to lock your `dtResult` to make it thread safe.

Comment: I get an error at line myTasks.Add(Task<MyModel>.Factory.StartNew(async () => ... saying that "Async lambda-expression cannot be converted to delegate type MyModel." Btw: The datatype of CurrIndex is CloudBlockBlob.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the async from it, which probably wasn't helping anyways in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I had to add Task.WaitAll(myTasks.ToArray()); to make it work and I added the Parallel.ForEach. Now its a way faster!